# Force directed graph in D3 not showing the graph

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to imitate a force directed graph from the d3.js website:  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I created my own example here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/vTRy5akEzGlhcfNblEDP?p=preview

Writing below junk code as pasting all the code will be overkill here:

```
<div class="left">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
```

However I am not able to see the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP and HTTPS don't mix very well. Since the page is served as HTTPS the script must also be https.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

or if [I correct your example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mBfJZKL5yjqyPOiCFUBh?p=preview)